# Http request post+get vb.net

Tags: vb.net, post, xmlhttprequest

whats up guys,

I've been looking about how to get or set byte to make post to login !
because each site have different string. if any one got (ONLY) the login source to this website : https://disqus.com/profile/login/

that will be a huge help from you guys.  Please

thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Keep in mind that we are here to help you with existing code, not write code for you. Please post the code you are having problems with.

Comment: i got the whole code, but as i said, i cant get the byte e.g:                                     Dim byteData As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("lsd=&charset_test=%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E6%B0%B4%2C%D0%94%2C%D0%84&version=1&ajax=0&width=0&pxr=0&gps=0&m_ts=&li=&email=" & email.Replace("@", "%40") & "&pass=" & pass & "&login=Connexion")
each site has unique byte code, thats my issue, i dont no where to get it   like in this link https://disqus.com/profile/login/